# Failure to connect to server in Dragon Dictation API

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am using a demo app from the dragon dictation api. I have made no modifications to the demo app, so I don't think there is anything wrong with it. When I open the app and run it on my phone it opens and runs. I click the record button and talk to it. Then it tries to connect to the server, but it gives me the error saying it can't connect to the speech server.

The output says:

```
2013-08-10 13:54:11.582 Recognizer[655:907] set session Active 0
2013-08-10 13:54:11.803 Recognizer[655:907] sample rate = 44100.000000
2013-08-10 13:54:11.823 Recognizer[655:907] audio input route(iOS5 or above): MicrophoneBuiltIn
2013-08-10 13:54:11.828 Recognizer[655:907] audiosource = MicrophoneBuiltIn
2013-08-10 13:54:11.889 Recognizer[655:907] [NMSP_ERROR] check status Error: 696e6974 init -> line: 485
2013-08-10 13:54:11.979 Recognizer[655:907] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-08-10 13:54:13.513 Recognizer[655:907] Recognizing type:'websearch' Language Code: 'en_US' using end-of-speech detection:2.
2013-08-10 13:54:14.517 Recognizer[655:907] Recording started.
2013-08-10 13:54:16.490 Recognizer[655:907] Recording finished.
2013-08-10 13:54:26.903 Recognizer[655:4103] [NMSP_ERROR] Connection timed out!
2013-08-10 13:54:27.167 Recognizer[655:907] Got error.
2013-08-10 13:54:27.170 Recognizer[655:907] Session id [(null)].
```

I have no clue what's going on here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all: "**Connection timed out!**". Can you specify the server configuration within your code? (If so, please update your question with the relevant code.)

Comment: check if account has expired or not?

Comment: @user1201204 : did you get this solved. I am facing same issue.Its throwing failed to connect to server

Comment: I had entered wrong APPLICATION KEY array (missed out last 2-3 letters) so the issue was "failed to connect to server" and it was solved by entering correct one.

Answer (score 1):

If when you try to record it immediately says “Cancelled” and shows an error like “recorder is null” or “[NMSP_ERROR] check status Error: 696e6974 init -> line: 485″, this probably means either something is wrong with your SpeechKit keys, or the SpeechKit servers are down. Double check your keys, and/or try again later.

Reference: http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri

Answer (score 0):

in my case the error was that i called the cancel: method on a nil SKRecognizer object.